# fetching file through sftp in nodejs not working

Tags: node.js, sftp

I am using `sftp-promises` module to fetch a csv file from client's sftp server and process it. I have been able to download csv from some sample ftp and sftp accounts using the same settings, but when I use my clien't original details, the connection fails. Most of the time, `ECONNRESET` error is being returned.
The only thing that is different for this sftp account is that when I connect to it using FileZilla, I need to specify Protocol as `FTP` and Encryption as 'Require explicit FTP over TLS'. I can't find any option related to this in sftp-promises module's configuration options.

EDIT:
I am not sure, but I googled about it more and it seems like my client's ftp connection is not `sftp` but 'ftps'. Now, I am not sure how to specify that while connecting using `sftp-promises`. Is there any other such module that I can use, and preferably that can work with all, 'ftps', 'ftp' and 'sftp'?